# Binding keys to operate on a specific pane

Tags: key-bindings, tmux

I have this key binding:

```
bind -rn C-Down last-pane \; send-keys "PageDown" \; last-pane
bind -rn C-Up last-pane \; send-keys "PageUp" \; last-pane
```

It works but I don't want it bound to the `last-pane,` I want it set the pane id I have in a variable: `@tmux_man_pane`.

Tried this:

```
bind -rn C-Down send-keys PageDown -t @tmux_man_pane
bind -rn C-Up send-keys PageUp -t @tmux_man_pane
```

And this:

```
bind -rn C-Down showw -v @tmux_man_pane \; send-keys "PageDown" \; showw -v @tmux_man_pane
bind -rn C-Up showw -v @tmux_man_pane \; send-keys "PageUp" \; showw -v @tmux_man_pane
```

Neither worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bind -rn C-Down run "tmux send-keys -t #{@tmux_man_pane} PageDown"